# only modify this class multiple elements same class javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem I have this JavaScript hide function the element itself is in a loop so there are multiple instances of it, i have this code but when I click on toggle button it modifies all of the elements instead of just the one I clicked here's the code:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $('.aval').hide().before('');
   $('a.toggle-aval').click(function() 
       {
        $('.aval').slideToggle(1000);
        return false;
   });
 });
//]]>
</script>
```

is there a way I can get it only to affect the clicked element?

Answer (score 2):

If the .aval element is inside a.toggle-aval, try this:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.aval').hide().before('');
   $('a.toggle-aval').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.aval').slideToggle(1000);
        return false;
   });
 });
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` to use the element that was clicked.  Assuming that the aval class element is a child of the toggle click.  It's impossible to tell without the html.  If they are indexed based you can access it via using the index of the clicked elemetn

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.aval').hide().before('');
   $('a.toggle-aval').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.aval').slideToggle(1000);
        // or
        $('.aval').eq( $(this).index() ).slideToggle(1000);
        return false;
   });
 });
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

tried all of that and half a dozen more variations before i found one that would work in the loop properly, here it is :

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function ()
              {
                    $('.container').each(function () {
                        $(this).find('.content').hide();
                        $(this).find('.button').click(function ()
                        {
                            $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle(1500);
                        });
                    });
              });
 //]]>
 </script>

.container , .content {display:block;}

 <span class="container">
  ......visable content
  <span class="button">
  more info 
  </span>

  <span class="content">
  .......hidden content
  </span>

  </span>
```